# Residue of a product of series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I need to find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-1}$ in $z=0$.

To do this, I proceeded to find the Laurent series of $f$ which is:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{k}$

Now I need the factor which multiplies $z^{-1}$ but I don't know how to operate with a product of series that have different expressions for the power of $z$

Comment: Did you mean $e^{1/z}$ rather than $e^{-z}$?  That's what would give you that Laurent series.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I want to write e^(z^(-1))

Comment: I think I corrected it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient of $z^{-1}$
in $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n}}{n!}\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \right)$ comes from multiplying terms $z^{-n}/n!$ and $z^{n-1}$.  Thus the coefficient is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $0$, its Laurent series there is actually a Taylor series and the residue is $0$.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding. I'm sorry, I am just a student, not an expert. How can I prove this?

Comment: My answer was for your *original* question. It is not my fault if you changed the question after I answered it.

Comment: I'm sorry... I realized after your answer.